# Layered Images for Email-specific HTML

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am looking for some insight on how to achieve a certain result with email-specific HTML+CSS. I've done some searching and I can't really find anything quite specific enough to fit my needs. I am a decently experienced front-end website designer/builder, but I am new to email HTML. My clients have always used a drag and drop service, but I want to be able to offer higher-quality email designs.

Here is an image that shows my desired outcome, with the green color being the background of the body of the email so that the shape just blocks out the correct parts of the image:

[image]

I know this might not be possible with the limited html/css that is required in email design, but if it is I'd love to see an example of it working or if anyone knows a good resource to learn the ins and outs of email code I'd really appreciate it.

My idea originally was to use image 1 as the background of a table, then the 2nd layer of the table, use image 2 as the background, or just add in the image inline with full width. I'd love to be able to put text positioned center, but again that might not be possible, I just don't know the limitations well.

Thanks!

Comment: When design HTML email, you should use the most simple as you can to be supported in most email clients. Layer or stack images is not recommended.

Comment: Background images with centered text should be relatively simple, if there were just one background image. Is it possible you can combine the images 1 & 2 programmatically, and therefore create this ideal situation?